# Is there a way to cancel screenshot taking in Preview?

Tags: screenshot, preview.app

Sometimes I choose "Take screenshot" > "Choose area" (not sure exactly because of translation) and understand that I want to scroll some content in the window, but I can't as it is not possible to scroll when you are taking screenshot.

Is there a way to do cancel it, without taking screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel the screenshot, just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Silly me ))) Really!